# Retrofitting column level encryption into an existing system?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have inherited a system that stores both passwords and Social Security Numbers in unencrypted columns.

I need to encrypt this data.

Are there any resources out there that cover how to retrofit this kind of change to a system?

This is an ASP VB web site project with a SQL Server Database.

I need information on handling this from both the front and back-end.

Thanks!

Comment: That's kind of horrifying. This wasn't in a production environment, was it?

Comment: Yes it is. What is the horrifying part? Oh and development....